# mSATA vs M.2 speed

Tags: ssd

I have a Mac Pro 2009 (4,1).

I have installed an mSATA SSD using an Addonics PCIe adapter.

I am wondering how this setup would compare with using an [M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) SSD instead? Is the M.2 supposed to be faster?

Comment: mSATA and M.2 are both form factors! It depends on the M.2 SSD and its bus interface (SATA-III or  PCI-e (1-4 lanes)) whether it is faster or not.